# populating ViewBag with HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have a controller with a method that is called when a button on my form is clicked. 
It populates a variable in my viewbag (a string containing html) and then i try to display the contents of this in my view.  For some reason, the contents of the viewbag doesnt change.
Here's the code in my controller:

```
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim TotalPSys As MyBusinessLayer.ListPSysAndMods = New ListPSysAndMods 
        ViewBag.HTMLForMods = "set"
        ViewBag.Test = "123"
        Return View(TotalPLC)
    End Function

  <HttpPost()>
    Function ShowModulesForPSys(ByVal strPSysID As String) As ActionResult
// .... do something....
        returnHTMLString = "<table><tr> <td>Show mods</td><td>Module Name</td></tr>"
        For Each moduleitem In modulelist
            returnHTMLString = returnHTMLString + " <tr> <td width='50%'  style='background-color:#5c87b2'><font color='white'>Number:</font> </td><td>Html.DisplayFor(Function(x) " + moduleitem.SlotNumber + ")</td>"
            returnHTMLString = returnHTMLString + "</tr><tr><td width='50%' style='background-color:#5c87b2'><font color='white'>RevNumber:</font></td>  <td>Html.DisplayFor(Function(x) " + moduleitem.RevisionNumber + ")</td>"
            returnHTMLString = returnHTMLString + "</tr><tr> <td width='50%'  style='background-color:#5c87b2'><font color='white'>IP Address:</font></td><td>Html.DisplayFor(Function(x) " + moduleitem.ModuleIP + ")</td></tr>"

        Next
        returnHTMLString = returnHTMLString + "</table>"
        'ViewData("HTMLForMods") = returnHTMLString
        ViewBag.HTMLForMods = returnHTMLString
        'MsgBox(ViewBag.HTMLForMods)
        ViewBag.Test = "456"
        MsgBox(ViewBag.Test)
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")

    End Function
```

The code in the view looks like:

```
         <p>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.HTMLForMods)</p>
         <p>@ViewBag.Test</p>
```

When the system displays the message box in the controller code, it displays the proper values. But when the view displays, it shows the correct initial values for the viewbag data, and then when i press my submit button, the code in the controller executes properly, but the viewbag displays the old data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are redirecting to index, so your **Viewbag.HtmlForMod** will be overwritten by what's defined in the index Action Method.

Comment: i tried removing the lines in the index function but that doesn't make a difference...and actually, i put a breakpoint in my index routine and it only gets called once - when the page loads. It doesn't get called again when i return view("index")

Comment: does it have to do with the httppost attribute on my function?  Here's why i think that might be the case.  I tried playing around the the home page and the about page that is created by default when you create an mvc template project.  It allows me to pass data around back and forth using the viewbag no problem... until I change the function that modifies the viewbag value to a HTTPPOST function.  Once I do that, it no longer works.

Comment: hey @dot, maybe you should try to use TempData instead of ViewBag because TempData is supposed to persist across different HTTPRequests which is what you are essentially doing with the Redirect, you still should hit the index on the redirect though.. not sure why that doesn't work